# Netsuite search salesorder by customfield

Tags: c#, netsuite

Have a salesorder opject and I want to search by using a tranid field.
how can I do that?
I know how to search by using internalid or extrenalid, but no clue about tranid

Comment: Is this in the UI or SuiteScript or What? Basically you would just add tranid as a filter if that's what you are trying to do. If it is in the UI tranid is also called document number often times

Comment: Sorry, people keep telling me not to use tags on the title and this time I listened. I am using C# to talk to the netsuite API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do this in C#.

```
SearchResult result = service.search(new TransactionSearch()
    {
        basic = new TransactionSearchBasic()
        {
            type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField() {
                @operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
                operatorSpecified = true,
                searchValue = new string[] { "_salesOrder" }
            },
            tranId = new SearchStringField()
            {
                @operator = SearchStringFieldOperator.@is,
                operatorSpecified = true,
                searchValue = "SO364886"
            }
        }
    }
);

if(result.status.isSuccess && result.totalRecords == 1)
{
    SalesOrder salesOrder = (SalesOrder)result.recordList[0];
    System.Console.WriteLine("Internal ID = " + salesOrder.internalId);
} else
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find sales order!");
}
```

Comment: Hi there. :) Thank you for that answer, I think I had something messed up on my reference because it wasn't letting me access the tranId field. Once I removed it and recreated it, I was able to access it. Thank you again for the assistance.